# resource files in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have included an obj(Wavefront .obj file) file as a resource with the attributes `Build action: None and Do not` `copy.`

How can I access these files from a c++ file later?. The resource file is in a c# project which is being compiled to an exe file. And the project where I want to access these resources are from a dll file?

If I change to Always copy I can access the file using the normal way:

```
ifstream file("Resources\\file.obj");
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you want? To access a C# resource from a C++ file? Is the .obj file the intermediate result of compilation?

Comment: the obj file is just a normal file, maybe a bad name, just a normal text file. Wavefront .obj file

Comment: Ok, so if it's part of your application and should be deployed may set "Always copy". Doesn't it work?

Comment: "Always copy" is not a possible solution even do it works:(

Comment: How do you deploy your application? You may simply put that file in the files to install.
(for developing you may, even if I don't understand why "Always copy" isn't viable, use pre-build actions.

Comment: Its a security thing why I cant have the obj file visible with the installation files.

Comment: So it should be "hidden" somewhere until application will be run? Anyway it'll be "visible" at that time. Can you consider to put it inside a DLL (or executable) and expose a function to unmanaged code to get it? It can be done in memory (or via _hidden_ temporary files).

Comment: yes its exactly what I want to do, to put it in an exe and use unmanaged code to get it.

Comment: The expose an unamanged function to extract the resource (but you can't do it in C#, you need to create another DLL in C++/CLI), your unmanaged C++ library will call that function. Inside that function you'll read the resource from the exe (of from the DLL itself) and you'll fill a buffer.
You may use a common syntax like:
void readresource(void* pBuffer, __int64* pBufferSize);
First call with NULL for pBuffer will set in pBufferSize the required size for the buffer, second call with the allocated buffer will copy the data into the buffer (I guess it's not too big).

Comment: Did you consider to keep it as file on disk but somehow encrypted?

Comment: I think encryption is to much for this. Its not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by right-clicking your ".obj" resource file. Go to "properties" and make sure "Exclude From Build" is set to "Yes."